# Trying to find violated Constraint in Gurobi - Linear Programming

Tags: optimization, constraints, linear-programming, gurobi

I am trying to implement a mechanism to list out if the specific constraint have been violated or not. I am using Gurobi, Kindly help me here

1) Minimise Constraint

2) Legality Constraint (ShiftCodelegality_A_Constraint,  ShiftCodelegality_B_Constraint)

3) Threshold Constraint (ShiftCodelegality_A__Threshold_Constraint, ShiftCodelegality_B__Threshold_Constraint)

I need to find it out by adding additional variables such as Extra_A, Extra_B, Extra_A_Legality, Extra_B_Legality.
So that i could use those variables values to understand if the constraint has violated.

Unmodified LP File  May be wrong, need ideas to implement

```
\ Model Shift Processing
\ LP format - for model browsing. Use MPS format to capture full model detail.
Minimize
  0.4 Person_593800_ShiftA + 0.2 Person_593800_ShiftB
Subject To
 Person_593800_Constraint: Person_593800_ShiftA + Person_593800_ShiftB + UNCOV_593800 = 1
 Person_862998_Constraint: Person_862998_ShiftA + Person_862998_ShiftB + UNCOV_862998 = 1
 ShiftCodelegality_A_Constraint: Person_593800_ShiftA + Person_862998_ShiftA
   <= 2
 ShiftCodelegality_B_Constraint: Person_593800_ShiftB + Person_862998_ShiftB
   <= 2
 ShiftCodelegality_A__Threshold_Constraint: Person_593800_ShiftA + Person_862998_ShiftA + UNCOV_ShiftAPOS_0
   = 1
 ShiftCodelegality_B__Threshold_Constraint: Person_593800_ShiftB + Person_862998_ShiftB + UNCOV_ShiftBPOS_0
   = 0
 MinimizedUncoverageConstraint: UNCOV_ShiftAPOS_0
   = 0
 PersonWiseAllocationConstraint: = 0
Bounds
Binaries
 Person_593800_ShiftA Person_593800_ShiftB Person_862998_ShiftA Person_862998_ShiftB UNCOV_593800
 UNCOV_862998 UNCOV_ShiftAPOS_0 UNCOV_ShiftBPOS_0
End
```

Below is the Modified LP file

```
\ Model Shift Processing
\ LP format - for model browsing. Use MPS format to capture full model detail.
Minimize
  0.4 Person_593800_ShiftA + 0.2 Person_593800_ShiftB + 50 Extra_A
Subject To
 Person_593800_Constraint: Person_593800_ShiftA + Person_593800_ShiftB + UNCOV_593800 = 1
 Person_862998_Constraint: Person_862998_ShiftA + Person_862998_ShiftB + UNCOV_862998 = 1
 ShiftCodelegality_A_Constraint: Person_593800_ShiftA + Person_862998_ShiftA + Extra_A
   <= 2
 ShiftCodelegality_B_Constraint: Person_593800_ShiftB + Person_862998_ShiftB + Extra_B
   <= 2
 ShiftCodelegality_A__Threshold_Constraint: Person_593800_ShiftA + Person_862998_ShiftA + UNCOV_ShiftAPOS_0 
   - Extra_A_Legality = 1
 ShiftCodelegality_B__Threshold_Constraint: Person_593800_ShiftB + Person_862998_ShiftB + UNCOV_ShiftBPOS_0
   - Extra_B_Legality = 0
 MinimizedUncoverageConstraint: UNCOV_ShiftAPOS_0 + UNCOV_ShiftBPOS_0
   = 0
 PersonWiseAllocationConstraint: = 0
Bounds
Binaries
 Person_593800_ShiftA Person_593800_ShiftB Person_862998_ShiftA Person_862998_ShiftB UNCOV_593800
 UNCOV_862998 UNCOV_ShiftAPOS_0 UNCOV_ShiftBPOS_0
End
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: i am trying list out the violated constraint against each solution and/or variable set as 0. For example if Person_593800_ShiftA = 0, i need to know which all constraint failed to satisfy so that Person_593800_ShiftA  is 0

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by  "if the specific constraint have been violated or not"?  At this point it's really unclear what you are asking, even with your addentum above.

Comment: Let's say if Person_593800_ShiftA = 1, then i need to understand if its because of constraint "ShiftCodelegality_A_Constraint" or "ShiftCodelegality_A__Threshold_Constraint" etc.. which was instrumental in making the decision.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask "which constraint caused the infeasibility" when you are talking about an *infeasible problem*. It makes sense when you are talking about an *infeasible solution* (you can just check which constraints the solution violates). But if the *problem* is infeasible, then the *set* of constraints are impossible to satisfy -- not just one of them (typically). Like, if I said, find the stock portfolio that maximizes your profit, s.t. buy at least 10 shares of stock A, and buy no more than 3 shares of stock A -- which constraint caused the infeasibility?